# DataGridView / ComboBox need two display states (long and short) for information

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I've got a DataGidView that's very tight on horizontal space, and a column that has rather lengthy descriptions.

What I'd like to do is create a ComboBox column that:

1. Displays a shortened version of the description
2. Has the full description in the drop-down
3. Behind the scenes deals with the actual value

So for example, I have this contrived example below.  The real list can have 20-30 items with text that's quite lengthy:

```
Code    Short      DropDown Text
 1      BigBox     Boxes larger than 6' x 6'
 2      SmBox      Boxes smaller than 6' x 6'
 3      BigBrl     Barrel 55 gallons
 4      SmBrl      Barrel less than 55 gallons
```

So what I want to show is:

[image]

When I open the dropdown I want to see:

[image]

And of course, when I query the value for the cell, I want "1".

I could split hairs and make the "short" description the first part of the longer description ("BigBx Boxes larger than 6' x 6'") but that doesn't seem right.

I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to accomplish this.  No code yet to show, since I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: Can you not return a fixed `SubString(0,MaxLength)` that you want. in your code when you do the query..? the `MaxLength` would be replaced with something like `Substring(0,25)` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change the DisplayMember of the combobox on the events DropDown and DropDownClosed.

On the Event DropDown, You'll want to change the DisplayMember to your Long Name.  One thing I discovered is that changing the DisplayMember resets the SelectedIndex, so you'll want to save that and then reset it after you've changed the display.

```
int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "LongNm";
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
```

You'll want to repeat this process with the DropDownClosed event and the Short Name to return to your closed display.

```
int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ShortNm";
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
```

The last problem I encountered was changing the width of the combobox dropdown.  I found code to do that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5801/Adjust-combo-box-drop-down-list-width-to-longest-s). 
The final code I had looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<ComboData> data;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data = new List<ComboData>();
        data.Add(new ComboData(1, "BigBox", "Boxes larger than 6x6"));
        data.Add(new ComboData(2, "SmBox", "Boxes small than 6x6"));
        data.Add(new ComboData(3, "BirBrl", "Barrel 55 Gallons"));
        data.Add(new ComboData(4, "smBrl", "Barrel less than 55 gallons"));

        comboBox1.DataSource = data;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ShortNm";
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "LongNm";
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;


        ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        int width = senderComboBox.DropDownWidth;
        Graphics g = senderComboBox.CreateGraphics();
        Font font = senderComboBox.Font;
        int vertScrollBarWidth =
            (senderComboBox.Items.Count > senderComboBox.MaxDropDownItems)
            ? SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth : 0;

        int newWidth;
        foreach (ComboData s in ((ComboBox)sender).Items)
        {
            newWidth = (int)g.MeasureString(s.LongNm, font).Width
                + vertScrollBarWidth;
            if (width < newWidth)
            {
                width = newWidth;
            }
        }
        senderComboBox.DropDownWidth = width;
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ShortNm";
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
    }
}

public class ComboData
{
    public int Code;
    public string ShortNm
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string LongNm
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ComboData(int c, string s, string l)
    {
        Code = c;
        ShortNm = s;
        LongNm = l;
    }
}
```

The end result looks like this:

[image: Closed Combobox]
[image: Open Combobox]

Answer (score 1):

I think I have nearly the thing you want. One small compromise: Whilr you're editing the value, the combobox displays the truncated long value. Otherwise this should suit you well.

My Source code is a slightly edited version of [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz.aspx). In the example they have an enum that is editable via a comboboxcolumn. My extension now changes the combobox to have a display and value member (the displaymember is the long text and the value member is the actual enum value) and when displaying the cell normally, the cell formatting event comes into play that overrides the display

These are the main changes:

```
private static T GetAttribute<T>(Enum value)
{
    T attribute = value.GetType()
        .GetMember(value.ToString())[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false)
        .Cast<T>()
        .SingleOrDefault();
    return attribute;
}

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CreateComboBoxWithEnums()
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    //combo.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Title));        

    var datatable = new DataTable(); //Setup a DataTable for your ComboBox Column
    datatable.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
    datatable.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(Title));

    foreach (Title item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Title)))
        datatable.Rows.Add(GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>(item).Description, item);

    combo.DisplayMember = "col1";
    combo.ValueMember = "col2";
    combo.DataSource = datatable;
    combo.DropDownWidth = 200;
    combo.DataPropertyName = "Title";
    combo.Name = "Title";
    return combo;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)//where Column1 is your combobox column
    {
        var val = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
        if (val != null)
        {
            e.Value = ((Title)val).ToString();
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}

public enum Title
{
    [Description("This better be thy king!")]
    King,

    [Description("aka wanna-be-king")]
    Sir
};
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/Mp9DRvDn

Comment: Trying this out: it's almost what I wanted.  Since I'm using the combobox in drop-down mode (no editing, just selection) it's a shame that after I make a selection the box still shows with the long description instead of the shorter one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the click event or the dropdown event to detect when the user tries to open the combobox. Then display a list box with the longer strings right below the combobox. When the user selects a string from the listbox, set the corresponding value in the combobox.